# Tidy-html5 on Mac OS: how to install

Tags: macos, terminal, htmltidy

Please help

I need to install HTML tidy on Mac OS
http://w3c.github.com/tidy-html5/

I call the commands in the Terminal and get nothing:

```
$ make -C build/gmake/
make: *** build/gmake/: No such file or directory.  Stop.

$ sh build/gnuauto/setup.sh && ./configure && make
sh: build/gnuauto/setup.sh: No such file or directory
```

What's the problem? What else should I install?

Answer (score 26):

The following worked for me:

```
brew update
brew install tidy-html5
```

Shell output:

```
➜  ~  brew install tidy-html5
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/tidy-html5-4.9.26.yosemite.
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring tidy-html5-4.9.26.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/tidy-html5/4.9.26: 8 files, 1.2M
```

Comment: **This is now the correct answer, the others are obsolete.**

Comment: Thanks for bringing it up! @Vladimir, kindly mark the answer correct if this worked for you!

Answer (score 15):

`tidy-html5` has been promoted to stable, so you should simply need to run in an up-to-date installation of [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) the command:

```
$ brew install tidy-html5
```

Comment: If tidy is already installed don't forget to first run "brew unlink tidy"

Comment: Installing with `--HEAD` worked for me. The only caveat being `tidy` ends up at `/usr/local/bin/tidy5`. Thanks @PedroRomano.

Comment: `tidy-html5` has been promoted to stable so the answer has been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

It didn't work for me, but here is what did:

Tap dupes repository:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
```

Homebrew dupes repository contains

> formulae [that] duplicate software provided by OS X, though may provide more recent or bugfix versions.

Then install from the dupes repository:

```
brew install tidy --HEAD
```

Comment: try `brew install tidyp`

Comment: This answer is the correct solution, not sure why it was down voted.

Comment: "tidyp does not validate HTML 5."

Answer (score 2):

To install [tidy5](https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5) which is the most up-to-date version of Tidy for OS X:

Ensure you have [homebrew](http://brew.sh) installed.

Then tap the dupes repository which provides brew recipes for new versions / bug fixes of software which is provided by the OS X system.

```
$ brew tap homebrew/dupes
```

Install Tidy (tidy-html5)

```
$ brew install --HEAD tidy
```

Untap the dupes repository

```
$ brew untap homebrew/dupes
```

To invoke

```
$ tidy5 -v  
> HTML Tidy for Mac OS X version 5.4.0
```

Comment: When I run `$ brew install --HEAD tidy` the install reaches the `==> make install` step, but then breaks on the following error: `Error: parent directory is world writable but not sticky` – any ideas? I'm not even sure which directory it's referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I've just installed the Tidy in Mac OS X 10.9.1:

```
brew install tidy
```

It will automatically install its dependencies: automake and libtool

And you may notice, I have a default tidy under /usr/bin/tidy, which has a version:

`HTML Tidy for Mac OS X released on 31 October 2006 - Apple Inc. build 15.12`

After installation of Homebrew, the version appears as

`HTML Tidy for Mac OS X released on 25 March 2009`

, under the path: /usr/local/Cellar/20090325/bin/tidy

Comment: Oh shoot, I forgot to update my `$PATH` so it was picking `/usr/bin/tidy` instead of `/usr/local/Cellar/tidy-html5/5.4.0/bin/tidy`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the documentation doesn't mention that you have to be in the bundle directory to run the first commands. The commands given are relative to the bundle directory.

Steps I just did successfully yesterday:

`cd ~/Library/Application Support/Avian/Pristine Copy/Bundles
git clone https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5
cd tidy-html5/
sudo make -C build/gmake/
sudo make install -C build/gmake/`

Not sure about the shared library part because I did not go through those steps.